# chown 0:0 ~/Applications/app/ = safe?

Tags: big-sur

I'm being asked to change permissions for app libs in my home directory to the root user to fix a problem on OSX.

Is this safe?

Comment: There's certainly no reason to do that.

Comment: Sounds fishy to me. Who or what is doing the asking?

Comment: Please be more specific: which directory do you need to change, which problem should this fix and who recommended the owner change?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yeap, this is 100% safe!

Changing file ownership to root *restricts* access, so if anything, would make it more "secure" depending on access modes set on the file. File ownership/modes on their own do not affect any execution privileges, so you don't need to worry about whether it would accidentally elevate execution privileges.

Now if you were told to run it as root (e.g. with `sudo`) or were told to use `setuid` on it, then you should be worried. These would in fact elevate execution privileges.